# Disable download button in HTML<audio> player in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I noticed that in new version of Chrome browser (55.x) the audio player (`HTML<audio>`) has download button. I see this button in Chrome only and I can't find anything about how to turn it off.

Code:

```
<audio src="audioUrl.mp3" controls=""></audio>
```

Ideally I'd like to hide this button but if hiding button is not possible I'd like to prevent downloading file when button pressed. I couldn't find any `ondownload` event where I could do such thing.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You could always create your own set of controls (very easy to do) and hide the built-in ones.

Comment: @ScottMarcus yep I know that and I surely do, but I was looking for quick fix as I'm very unhappy because of this button

Comment: Question is on Audio but duplicate link is on Video. Anyway, I found this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41302624/2912339

Answer (score -1):

**"In reality, you can't. But you can make it harder to download."**

The full response is here: [Prevent HTML5 video from being downloaded (right-click saved)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756837/prevent-html5-video-from-being-downloaded-right-click-saved)

Comment: The question wasn't about how to prevent downloading per se. It was about how to prevent the button from being visible.

Comment: So, it doesn't address the question as asked and it just links to another question? Who up-voted this?