# hide the download option in video tag

Tags: html, html5-video

how to hide the download option in html5 video tag.
I put `controlsList='nodownload'` in the video tag and its fine but the download button only shows in when the client open the video link in `Gionee  Mobile phone` .

Please help, thank you

Comment: some browsers won't support proper HTML5 standards. I think "Gionee phone" browser is one of those.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Chrome 55, prevent showing Download button for HTML 5 video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115801/in-chrome-55-prevent-showing-download-button-for-html-5-video)

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it via CSS. Code taken from here: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-disable-the-download-button-from-the-controls-in-HTML5-video-for-Google-Chrome

```
CSS

video::-internal-media-controls-download-button {
    display:none !important;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
    overflow:hidden !important;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
    width: calc(100% + 30px) !important; /* Adjust as needed */
}
```

EDIT: if you absolutely must hide the download button, then maybe you could do a customized video player. [Mozilla has a nice article on how to do it and style it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/Video_player_styling_basics). This should work for any browser (but you might want to check first if your particular browser supports all methods involved).

EDIT2: There are cutomized players out there already. I found [OzPlayer](http://www.accessibilityoz.com/ozplayer/) as an example.

Comment: its not working sir, actually the site is open in a wrapper app

Comment: @dom Hmmm strange, maybe it's what Prajwal said, this varies according to browser. Maybe you could erase both the "controls" attribute and the "controlsList" attribute? And what do you mean by a "wrapper app"? You mean that the HTML is not opened by Gionee phone browser, but by an app? Then it will depend on the app's code. Honestly, I don't think that hiding the download button will prevent user from downloading video (remember user can modify the DOM via console, for example), there are thousands of plugins enabling regular users to download video from `<video>`

Comment: at least the problem is solved using the OZPlayer


<figure id='ozplayer-1-container' class='ozplayer-container'>
<div data-responsive='ozplayer-1-container' data-controls='stack' class='ozplayer' id='ozplayer-1'>
<video  poster="http://my_site.com/_uploads/video/thumb/22.jpg" width='640' height='360' controls='controls' preload='none'>
<source src='".$p['path']."' type='video/mp4'></source>
<div class='ozplayer-fallback'><ul><li><a href='".$p['path']."'>Video for playback</a></li></ul></div>
</video>
</div>
</figure>

 Thanks for all your help, many many thanks