# how to remove downloading option fom <a> tag

Tags: html, css

how to remove download option from a tag is it possible?

`<a controls controlsList="nodownload" href="admin/upload/<?php echo $row['files']?>" class="venobox play-btn mb-4"data-vbtype="video"  data-autoplay="true"></a>`

Comment: You put content on the web, it will be downloaded. The attribute you use should work for Chrome but only for the video tag. Here are some more tricks that will not stop anyone seriously interested in downloading your content: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115801/in-chrome-55-prevent-showing-download-button-for-html-5-video