# How can I remove the download button on facebook video previews on Chrome?

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, video, facebook-opengraph, jwplayer

Using Chrome browser, when I share a link from my website on facebook, the 'preview' is a video in mp4 format i.e **not swf** format. **The problem** is that a download button is showing up on the video player on facebook.

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39602852/disable-download-button-for-google-chrome/40975859) I was able to remove the download button on my website using `controlsList="nodownload"` attribute, but I still can't remove it from facebook posts.

As far as I know, this video preview is built based just OG metatags, which I believe are correct:

```
<meta property="og:video:url" content="https://cdn.domain.com/path/to/video/file.mp4" />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://cdn.domain.com/path/to/video/file.mp4" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="768" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="432" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4" />
```

Question: Is there anything I can do to fix this or does it depends 100% on facebook?

Note: Due to privacy policies I can't share here an example but [here is an example with similar OG metatags](https://www.ft.com/video/5dfc2391-4375-4ee3-864c-cd11df2f8f5e?playlist-name=editors-picks&playlist-offset=2), post it on your facebook timeline and you'll see the download button as shown in this screenshot example below : https://i.stack.imgur.com/mck0N.png

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Confirmed, it's 100% on facebook side. This is the response I got from Facebook https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/605686286306392/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question: Is there anything I can do to fix this or does it depends 100% on facebook?

This is entirely on Facebook's end.

You've provided Facebook with the URL to your video content. How they present it is up to them.