# How to set the download file extension for blob data

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video, blob

In my site video use the blob data, when the video was downloaded, the saved filename is the blob name with `.txt`(`4671addc-3ce0-4eb6-b414-ddf3406b1fe5.txt`) extension in Chrome borwser, while in firefox is with `.mp4`(`4671addc-3ce0-4eb6-b414-ddf3406b1fe5.mp4`) extension.

How can I specific the download file extension and the filename.

I've tried to set it with below code, but none works.

```
    type="video/mp4"
    filename="111.mp4"
    download="111.mp4"
```

Here is the sample code, I use now.

```
<video 
    width="300px"
    id="video"
    type="video/mp4"
    filename="111.mp4"
    download="111.mp4"
    controls=""
    src="blob:http://localhost/4671addc-3ce0-4eb6-b414-ddf3406b1fe5">
</video>
```

Comment: Use the `download` for data uri works as the question [Is there any way to specify a suggested filename when using data: URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/283956/6521116)  shows. But not works here for the blob uri.

Comment: Solution in [How to set name of file downloaded from browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3102226/6521116) also not works here.

Comment: [How to modify the internal media controls download event of video tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71700860/6521116)

Comment: Solve by specific the blob type when create the blob data. `var blob = new Blob([buffer],{'type': 'video/mp4'})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### using HTML5 `download` attribute download the `Blob` URL file

> Notice

`download` attribute only for HTML5 `a` or `area` tag ✅

`download` attribute not exist on HTML5 `video` tag ❌

### download `Blob` URL image

```html
<section>
  <img id="img" />
  <a id="img-link" download>...loading</a>
</section>
```

```js
// ES5
function generatorBlobURL(url, type, dom, link) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
  xhr.onload = function(res) {
    var blob = new Blob(
      [xhr.response],
      {'type' : type},
    );
    var urlBlob = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    // render `blob` url ✅
    dom.src = urlBlob;
    // using `a` tag download ✅
    link.href = urlBlob;
    link.innerText = urlBlob;
    link.download = filename;
  };
  xhr.send();
}

(function() {
  var type = 'image/png';
  var url = 'https://cdn.xgqfrms.xyz/logo/icon.png';
  var dom = document.querySelector('#img');
  var link = document.querySelector('#img-link');
  var arr = url.split('/');
  var filename = arr[arr.length - 1] || 'default-filename';
  generatorBlobURL(url, type, dom, link, filename);
})();
```

### download `Blob` URL video

```html
<section>
  <video id="video" controls width="400" height="300">
    loading...
  </video>
  <br>
  <a id="video-link" download>...loading</a>
</section>
```

```js
// ES5
function generatorBlobURL(url, type, dom, link) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
  xhr.onload = function(res) {
    var blob = new Blob(
      [xhr.response],
      {'type' : type},
    );
    var urlBlob = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    // render `blob` url ✅
    dom.src = urlBlob;
    // using `a` tag download ✅
    link.href = urlBlob;
    link.innerText = urlBlob;
    link.download = filename;
  };
  xhr.send();
}

(function() {
  var type = 'video/mp4';
  var url = 'https://cdn.xgqfrms.xyz/HTML5/Blob/2022-04-07-sh.mp4';
  var dom = document.querySelector('#video');
  var link = document.querySelector('#video-link');
  var arr = url.split('/');
  // arr.at(-1);
  var filename = arr[arr.length - 1] || 'default-filename';
  setTimeout(() => {
    generatorBlobURL(url, type, dom, link, filename);
  }, 0);
})();
```

### live demo

https://codepen.io/xgqfrms/full/YzYRLwg

> screenshots

[image]
[image]

### refs

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attributes
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes

Comment: This is an image blob. Video is not like this, video download is from the video player.

Comment: HTML5 `download` attribute is designed for `a` tag, not for the `video` tag; you should create your custom event handler or wrap it using `a` tag.

Comment: try this lib `https://videojs.com/`

Comment: What if we don't know the file extension exactly. Is it possible to specify file extension based on the received blob?

Comment: @AliBaghban Of course! for more details see this demo https://codepen.io/xgqfrms/full/ExEgKjQ

Comment: But in what cases do you not know exactly the file extension? you create the blob file with the full path `url`, so should know the file extension.

Comment: @xgqfrms Oops, you are right. I was missing the part where I could get the extension from the URL itself. Thanks for pointing it out.